# MySQL to PostgreSQL - Find in array, and count array values

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I've a `colors` table and an `items` table, with a **many to many** relation between these 2 tables (via an `items_colors` table). An item can have many colors and a color can have many items.

```
items
   id

colors
   id
   name

items_colors
    item_id [foreign key: items(id)]
    color_id [foreign key: colors(id)]
```

I'm currently migrating from **MySQL** to **PostgreSQL**. This SQL query below is working well with MySQL, but I'm not able to make it works on PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT i.*
FROM
    items i
    JOIN items_colors ic ON ic.item_id = i.id
    JOIN colors c ON c.id = ic.color_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM( c.name IN ('green', 'blue') )
```

A also tried to express the `HAVING` differently:

```sql
HAVING SUM( c.name NOT IN ('green', 'blue') ) = 0;
```

In all cases, with PostgreSQL I'm getting this error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  function sum(boolean) does not exist
LINE 7: HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM( c.name IN ('green'...
                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

*(Just for the context and the goal of this query, I want to get all items that **only match** one or more provided colors (from a provided array of colors). If an item is also associated with an additional color that is not specified in the array, it should not be retrieved. In my example above I'm getting **all** items that match the given array, so all items that have green, or blue, or green and blue color(s). **But** if an item has the blue and also the red colors (or only red, or no color), it is excluded from the results.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in Postgres, assuming that `items.id` is the primary key:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i JOIn
     items_colors ic
     ON ic.item_id = i.id JOIN
     colors c
     ON c.id = ic.color_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM( (c.name IN ('green', 'blue'))::INT );
```

Or:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.name IN ('green', 'blue'))
```

A version that works in both databases is:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN c.name IN ('green', 'blue') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's now working perfectly, and I'm learning to use PostgreSQL better!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM
    items i
    JOIN items_colors ic ON ic.item_id = i.id
    JOIN colors c ON c.id = ic.color_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(c.name) <@ ARRAY['green', 'blue'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm discovering the array operators in PostgreSQL and it looks very interesting! However here I'm getting `Query 1 OK` without rows.

Comment: @Etienne: Please check this fiddle, the SQL works fine, it might be something in your application code. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9248eb40c97d28c8c2aceb2dc88e7c22

Comment: Yes it work well in your dbfiddle. Not sure why it doesn't on my side. I've double checked and I'm getting this error (on PostgreSql 12.5):
```sql
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] <@ text[]
LINE 7: HAVING ARRAY_AGG(c.name) <@ ARRAY['green', 'blue'];
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```
Anyway I've now a working solution, but I'm curious about that one.

Comment: @Etienne: Both items must be the same datatype, both VARCHAR or both TEXT. I never use VARCHAR in my databases, only TEXT, and never had this issue.